# FileInfo.Path shows Value does not fall within the expected range exception when move file to another folder

Tags: c#, file, path, uwp, directory

How to cope with the path that exceeds the maximum character?

I want to move a file to another folder that is in accordance with the wishes of the user. But is plagued by error messages, as shown below:
[image: error message]

code:

```
string path = (carousel.SelectedItem as Book).FileInfo.Path;
StorageFile file1 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri((carousel.SelectedItem as Book).FileInfo.Path, UriKind.Absolute));
await file1.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, ((carousel.SelectedItem as FileInformation).Name), NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog a = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Moved" + (carousel.SelectedItem as Book).Name, "To" + ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path);
await a.ShowAsync();
```

How to handle it?

Comment: Post a sample value of a `Book.FileInfo.Path`

Comment: I've found a solution, but  I am not sure it relates to it: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be8eafdc-f880-4186-81da-d1d8dac133f5/storagefilegetfilefromapplicationuriasync-stopped-working-in-release-preview?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: This project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4oRSWSS0hKDMmV6QzBzZ3RDNlU/view?usp=sharing . Steps: 1. Click "buku" button and select the book you want to download. 2. The book will be kept on KoleksiPage. 3. to create a folder, click the "Tambah Folder" button. 4. To move a file to another folder, click the "Pindah ke folder" button. 5. to open the books that have been downloaded (without downloading the book and when the book is already there), click the "koleksi" button on the MainPage.

Comment: I'm having trouble moving the folder. I've been asked to hand syncfusion and get an answer that is too long path so that the file can not be moved to another folder. How to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't look like it's related to exceeding maximum characters. GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync expects an application URI (e.g. "ms-appx:///foo.txt") not an arbitrary path.

Since you have a full path use StorageFile.[GetFileFromPathAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync.aspx)

If the FileInfo already includes the StorageFile then use that directly rather than converting to a path and back.

Comment: I need to move files to other folders, so it is necessary to take his path. Or is there another way?